How do you get price in UniswapV3?
Seriously I'm on this for like two weeks or more and please help me I'm going crazy. I want to get the price with smart contract not js way that can be handled with sdk I know but How do I do it in my smart contract. I just need to get the price thats all.

in uniswap v3 you can get the price from sqrtX96 price and tick from the pool smart contract. check this blog for the help
https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-math-primer

Found this guide thx for help
